# Libgdx supporting all Android Pixel Densities

Tags: libgdx, render

I have made an android/ios game and it was working fine on Android only one I have published but say I make a texture render 50px by 50px the pixel density on other devices make the texture render differently is there a way I can make fixed world coordinates so the images render the same but instead of the texture rendering at random sizes it just scales down/up

Comment: Use a `Camera` for this. If you are using the newest libgdx version you can also use `ViewPort`.

Comment: @Springrbua I am rendering using Textures will that effect how things are drawn to the screen? And using a camera and viewport will that effect any texture positioning when implemented or can I implement this in the ApplicationListener class and everything will adjust automatically? Also how would I go about implementing this? Thank you so much for your help I just dont wanna give up on my game

Comment: Never give up you can always learn new things and it is not that hard. I write an answer about cameras, but for viewport you have to look yourself, as i never used them,  i stil use version 9.9.

Comment: @Springrbua I am using libgdx 0.9.9 have you ever came across into this problem I have been trying to find the solution for days and I cant :( Because say on my phone every inch is like 150 pixels but on someone elses its 200 if I try and draw a Texture at a width of 150 pixels on my phone its going to be bigger and on theirs smaller.

Comment: This was always a problem for developers, and it will always stay a problem, but you can have it easier with the method i wrote in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up a `Camera` like this:

1. `new OrthographicCamera(viewPortWidth, viewPortHeight)` for 2D game
2. `new PerspectiveCamera(viewAngel, viewPortWidth, viewPortHeight)` for 3D.

I stay with 2D for now. The viewport you set will automatically be scaled up to fit the window/screen. So if you use a viewport of 80 width and 45 height on a 1600 * 900px window, every unit gets scaled up to use 20px. On a 800*450px screen one unit would only use up 10px.
The origin of your camera (P(0,0)) is in the middle of the screen by default. So if you render a `Texture` at x = 0, y = 0, with a wide of 1 and a height of one, its left lower corner is in the middle of the screen, and it is 20px*20px big (on the 1600*900 screen).
To have the cameras origin at the lower left corner of the screen (as we normally want it), you need to move it by calling `camera.translate(viewPortWidth/2, viewPortHeight/2)` or by seting its position: `camera.position.set(viewPortWidth/2, viewPortHeight/2)`. After that you have to call `camera.update()` to let it know that you moved it. To that after every change on the camera (rotate, translate...).
To use this camera to render your `Texture`s you have to set the `SpriteBatch`s `projectionMatrix`, which is like the view of the world or something like this. To do this you call: `spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)`. Then if you draw with this `spriteBatch` everything should work.

Something to read: [Projection, viewport, camera](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Projection,-viewport,-&-camera)
[The new Viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports)

Comment: holy crap thanks @Springrbua I will get back to you with results

Comment: Sorry to ask this silly question but with the viewport how you said 80 width and 45 height how did you know it will equal 20px on a 1600 * 900px screen? and is using 80 by 45 just like invisible coordinates?

Comment: When you set the width of the cameras viewport you say: I want to have 80 units on my screen width. So it says i have 1600px and i want to have 80 units, so 1600/80 = 20 px/unit.

Comment: Oh and another question, will I have to go through and update the position and size of every texture in the game or will putting this camera into the game automatically adjust everything? Sorry for all the questions but where you put the 80 and 45 is that the best size that will suit the majority of phones and tablets because they would have to follow a ratio wouldnt they?

Comment: It depends on your game. It is just a value that fit for me in my games, because i said i want to have 80 units in width and i want a 16/9 aspect ratio.
And yea if you calculated positions in pixels until now you have to redo it. To have it easier think about your units as meter. For example your cahracter is about  2 meters tall. If you want the character to be as tall as half of the screen height, the your viewport heigth should be 4. Then, depending on your aspect ration set the width.

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me time and my reputation :)

Comment: I saved your reputation? 1 xD How can i save that? xD No problem i'm glad i could help. If you have any other questions feel free to ask. SO is a great community, which helped me a lot with libgdx (i started with libgdx a few month ago xD). Let me see your progress if you have something ready :P

Comment: @Springbua will that also mean my images should follow a certain aspect ratio? Or how will I go about doing an asect ratio for the screen with this new way? Ill send you a link to my website when I upload it, I recently uploaded it and it was a failure many peoples phones didnt work and I had a few people that downloaded the game

Comment: Well you have to try. Ofc if your `Texture` is 20px wide and 5 px heigh and you say it should be 1 unit wide and 1 heigh it will look ugly, as it gets stretched in y-direction. But you can also say your texture should be for example 4 units wide and 1.5f units heigh, for example for a car on side view. To have a fixed aspect ratio there are different methods. Just google "libgdx keep aspect ratio" and you will find a lot.

Comment: I also use Stage for some text rendering how would I go about scaling that?

Comment: A `Stage` has its own camera. So you can use `Stage.getCamera().setViewport(yourWidth, yourHeight);` or something like this. It also has its onw `SpriteBatch`, so you can use `stage.getSpriteBatch().setProjectionmatrix(stagecam.combined)` or something like this. Important note: before calling stage.draw() make sure you call `end()` on the other `SpriteBatch`, as two batches at the same time don't work well together...

Comment: Thank you so much, do you think Ill have to redo my images?

Comment: Depends on how your images look. But if they fit to your game until now they will do in future, if you don't change the scaling. I suppose you had your game working on one device, as you have uploaded it. So if on this device their size was 1/20 of the screen size and you stay with this they won't look to ugly. But ofc if someone plays the game on a monsterscreen they will be scaled up a lot and there for not look that good. But you have to test and if it does not look good to you change it.

Comment: with the width being 480 and height 320 will anything related to input need to be changed since im not measuring by pixels

Comment: if you are using touchpositions, you have to use `camera.unproject()` or something like this. But i think you will find some tutorials about this when you google. Also on SO there are a lot of answers to this

Comment: Thanks :) your help is extremely appreciated

Comment: please note that libgdx changed! take a look at the Viewport Classes https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports . It now gives you a simple solution for suporting different resoultions. See this blog entry http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3322

Comment: @BennX thanks for pointing that out. I allready linked to the `Viewport` artikle on github, but as he said he is using version 0.9.9, like me, he does not have `Viewport` class.

Comment: Okay but it is the newer approach and worth a try because it is really easy to understand with the new architecture.

Comment: Yea of course it is worth a try. And i think it is pretty easy to use. At least it seems so.